# Scoping order of '=' and '<-' inside a function in R

Tags: r

I am trying to understand how R scopes variables inside a function. Why is the output 12? Why not 4? How are a & b assigned here

I am learning R. Please explain with some references

```
f1 <- function(a = {b <- 10; 2}, b = 2) {
  a+b
}

f1()
```

Comment: In the function definition `b = 2` is a promise, not an actual value. Since you assign the value with `b <- 10` the promise will not be evaluated.

Comment: Try changing to `function(a = {2}, b = {2; print(b)})` and see the error message.

Comment: Thank you. Yes it resulted in an error and I got partial understanding of whats happening. But, are not both <- and = assignment operators? Or maybe they work different in a function argument?

Comment: They work completely differently in function arguments or when assigning a value to an argument when calling a function. In function arguments you should only use `=`. Unless you want to get into trouble.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is explained in [section 4.3.3 of the R Language manual](https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-release/R-lang.html#Argument-evaluation).

> When a function is called, each formal argument is assigned a promise
>   in the local environment of the call with the expression slot
>   containing the actual argument (if it exists) and the environment slot
>   containing the environment of the caller. If no actual argument for a
>   formal argument is given in the call and there is a default
>   expression, it is similarly assigned to the expression slot of the
>   formal argument, but with the environment set to the local
>   environment.
>
> The process of filling the value slot of a promise by evaluating the
>   contents of the expression slot in the promise’s environment is called
>   forcing the promise. A promise will only be forced once, the value
>   slot content being used directly later on.

Nothing has a value until the sum starts getting computed. First `a` is required and so it's expression is evaluated. The promise for `b` is lost as it gets assigned a value directly during the forcing of `a` and so the actual `b` assignment promise in the function definition is not evaluated at all.

If the order is the other way round, you see a different result:

```
f2 <- function(a = 2, b = {a <- 10; 2}) {
  a+b
}

f2()
[1] 4
```

However, note that the value of `a` will be 10 at end of the function, but 2 when it is required during the sum. Both promises get evaluated here.

If the order of the sum is reversed in `f1` to instead be `b+a` you would find similar behaviour to `f2`.

Earlier in that section there is a general warning that side-effects should be avoided in assignments because they is no guarantee they will be evaluated.

> R has a form of lazy evaluation of function arguments. Arguments are
>   not evaluated until needed. It is important to realize that in some
>   cases the argument will never be evaluated. Thus, it is bad style to
>   use arguments to functions to cause side-effects. While in C it is
>   common to use the form, foo(x = y) to invoke foo with the value of y
>   and simultaneously to assign the value of y to x this same style
>   should not be used in R. There is no guarantee that the argument will
>   ever be evaluated and hence the assignment may not take place.

Comment: to make clear that arguments are evaluated as they are needed it might be helpful to include the example: 
`f3 <- function(a = {b <- 10; 2}, b = 2) {
  b+a
}
` which will evaluate as 4, because now `b` is the first variable in the function body.

Comment: One small error (a typo?):  "The promise for `b` gets forced when the expression for `a` is evaluated," is not right.  When the expression for `a` is evaluated, the promise for `b` gets replaced by the fixed value `10`.  The promise is never forced.  Maybe you meant to say "The promise for `a` gets forced when the expression for `a` is evaluated,"?

Comment: @AaronHayman Yes, I'll edit to make it clearer. The value of the variable will still change, but only during the computation of the sum

Comment: @user2554330 It depends on if you see the binding of a value to a promised variable to be a forcing of the promise with a new expression, or a new binding that discards the previous promise. But I think my explanation could be clearer, so I'll edit.

Comment: @James, I think you are misunderstanding how R works.  A "promised variable" is just a variable that has a promise bound to it.  When you bind something else to that variable, it is isn't special at all.  You can tell the difference between a forced promise and a fixed value by looking at `substitute(b)`.  If `b` holds a forced promise, you'll see the expression that was forced.  If it holds a fixed value, you'll just see that value.

Comment: @user2554330 OK, yes I see now, clarified it again.

Comment: Thanks, much better now.

Answer (score 1):

Refer https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/base/versions/3.5.2/topics/assignOps[enter link description here](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/base/versions/3.5.2/topics/assignOps)

Try this

```
f1 <- function(a = {b <= 10; 2}, b = 2) {

  a+b
}

f1()
```

or

```
f1 <- function(a = {b <<- 10; 2}, b = 2) {

      a+b
    }

    f1()
```

Comment: Care to explain?

Comment: If you down voted this, please remove. I am trying to understand why the output is 12 not how to get 4. I modified the question accordingly